# Name resolution for Java

Tags: java, compiler-construction, programming-languages

I am currently writing a compiler for a big subset of java and i can't seem to find anything useful for name resolution techniques. Can you please point me towards some resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The VM specification for class file format](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html) contains the naming conventions expected by the various types of names used in the JVM.

They differ slightly (not by much) depending on whether you are referring to a class name, a package name, a member name, or a method signature.

As far as name resolution techniques, you need to ensure that you follow the resolution rules as laid out [in the Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html).

Basically, if you violate the rules laid out in the language spec (or the names expected in the class file spec), then you violate how the Java language works, or what the class loader expects (respectively).